# A sort query in SQL by special criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `products`, and a table `product-languages`.

```
products:
prd_id|prd_name

product-languages:
prd_id|language_id|prd_name
1     |1          |Product_German_name
1     |2          |Product_English_name
1     |4          |Product_French_name
```

I want to join product-languages on `prd_id` and then sort it by my priority list of `language_id` (for example: 2,1,4) - first I want the result of `lang_id=2`, if this is not available I want to have `lang_id=1` as the first result.

Is this possible in SQL? I think my personal order list is the problem, because I would have to check if that `lang_id` is even available...

Subquery maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in standard SQL via `case` with something like:

```
select
  *
from
  products p,
  product_languages l
where
  p.prd_id = l.prd_id
order by
  (case language_id
   when 2 then 1
   when 1 then 2
   when 4 then 3
   end) asc
```

Comment: Maybe also a group by so I only get one dataset for each product?

Comment: Group by (prd_id) I guess.

Comment: Yes, `group by p.prd_id` in my query would restrict it to the first matched row of the set.  [Here's a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c7e5c/2) showing it in action.

Comment: Great thanks, had to do a manual group by with php because of the mysql-aggregation-error on this row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL, but you can do it.  One method uses variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@prd_id = prd_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@prd_id := prd_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from producct_languages t join
           (select @prd_id := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by prd_id, field(language_id, 2, 1, 4)
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Can you show which t is which table? Im missing the hint for the prd_language table. Thanks.